SPF record is set, but mail testers are giving me high severity risk
I'm using sendmail and I have the following SPF record:
"v=spf1 a mx a:hostinger.com ip4:ip_here -all"

And it gives me this description:
domain.com. 14400 IN TXT v=spf1 a mx a:hostinger.com ip4:ip_here -all


Status: none
Message: hostname_here: No applicable sender policy available
Receiver: p-pm-inboundg02a-aws-useast1a
Identity: mailfrom
Envelope-from: domain@hostname
Helo: hostname
Client-ip: ip_here

And it says this :
You do not have a SPF record, please add the following one to your domain hostname_here:

v=spf1 a mx ip4:ip_here ~all

But I already set the SPF record and have waited more than 3 days for propagation.

The SPF check uses the MAIL FROM domain (from the email's Return-Path header) as input. In your reports, the MAIL FROM address is referred to as envelope-from.
Your email's MAIL FROM address is poobel@srv475934.hstgr.cloud and the domain used for the SPF check is srv475934.hstgr.cloud. Since srv475934.hstgr.cloud does not have an SPF record, the SPF check fails.
You should look into changing the MAIL FROM (envelope-from) address in Postfix to your own domain.

I'm using sendmail, I was looking in senmail.mc file to see where I can change the domain, but I couldn't find where, any idea where I can change it?

I'm not familiar with sendmail, but this answer might be a good starting point.
